# WP wp_ajax_function is not calling PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress plugin for a cookie notice, i want the cookies to be created with PHP. And the button in the notice bar is supposed to run a php function, ajax is not really working with me right now.

My ajax request is being processed as far as i know, in the network tab it shows admin-ajax.php with status 200, but it just won't call the actual function.

this is my code

**Main plugin file**

```
function setAjaxCallbacks(){

add_action('wp_ajax_accepted', 'accepted');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_accepted', 'accepted');

}

add_action('init', 'setAjaxCallbacks');


function accepted(){

    die('test');
    echo 'LOLALLES';
    global $wpdb;
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    $whatever += 10;
    echo $whatever;
    wp_die('0 ', 400);

    echo '<script>
        alert("jhwgvbht ij")
    </script>';
    wp_die();
}

isset($_COOKIE['cookieBar']) or setCookieBar();

function setCookieBar()
{
    if (!is_admin()){

        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script_custom');

        function enqueue_script_custom()
        {
            wp_enqueue_style('CookieBarStyle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/styles.css');
            wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', plugins_url('/js/my_query.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
            wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
                array('ajaxurl2' => 'https://wordpressjip.jmulder.dt2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 'we_value' => 1234));

            wp_print_scripts('ajax-script');
        }
        ?>

        <div class="cookieBar" id="cookieBar" style="display: block">
            <p align="center"></p>

            <button id="submitCookies" class="submitCookies" name="accepted">Accepteer</button>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
```

**my_query.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
jQuery(".submitCookies").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl2,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'accepted',
            whatever: 1234
        },
        succes: function (response) {
            return response;
        }
    })
})
});
```

Comment: There's no function called **accepted** in your sample. And I suggest you add some namespacing - like, adding a prefix to your functions (like **cookie_bar_accepted** and **cookie_bar_setCookieBar**), to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Can you please check the ajax urls working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Function named "accepted" is inside another function, that's why it is not working. You need to learn how ajax is working in wordpress. Please go through following link. It will teach you how to use ajax in wordpress https://medium.com/techcompose/how-to-use-ajax-precisely-in-wordpress-custom-themes-dc61616720a8

Following code may help you:

```
<?php

function setAjaxCallbacks()
{
    add_action('wp_ajax_accepted', 'accepted');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_accepted', 'accepted');
}

add_action('init', 'setAjaxCallbacks');


function accepted()
{
    echo 'LOLALLES';
    global $wpdb;
    $whatever = intval($_POST['whatever']);
    $whatever += 10;
    echo $whatever;
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script_custom');

function enqueue_script_custom()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('CookieBarStyle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/styles.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', plugins_url('/js/my_query.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script(
        'ajax-script',
        'ajax_object',
        array('ajaxurl2' => 'https://wordpressjip.jmulder.dt2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 'we_value' => 1234)
    );

    wp_print_scripts('ajax-script');
}


function setCookieBar()
{
    if (!is_admin()) {
        if (! isset($_COOKIE['cookieBar'])) {
            ?>

        <div class="cookieBar" id="cookieBar" style="display: block">
            <p align="center"></p>

            <button id="submitCookies" class="submitCookies" name="accepted">Accepteer</button>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'setCookieBar' );
```

Comment: The function accepted is clearly there in the code. The problem is its inside of another function. Rather than link off to somewhere else why not try and fix his code for him :)

Comment: @DhananjayKyada I've tried it, didn't work, is there an other way you might know